# reduce vertical space for \xrightarrow

Tags: amsmath

I find the vertical spacing of `amsmath`'s `\xrightarrow` too large for the underset. Is there an easy way to reduce it (i.e. put "below" close to the arrow, in the example)?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\fbox{$\xrightarrow[\fbox{below}]{\fbox{above}}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I looked at the arrow definition (`ext@arrow`, e.g. discussed in [Understanding ext@arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57148/understanding-extarrows)) and there, `\limits^{}_{}` is used.

PS. I am interested in a short and simple solution. I know how to built a new extensible arrow from scratch, but wanted to know if there is an easier solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Just a note: prefer the `article` class instead of `minimal` for MWEs. See also [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Comment: See if the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94572/3954 helps you here.

Comment: Short answer: no, if you want to rely on the same mechanism, which essentially is `\mathop{<arrow>}\limits^{<above>}_{<below>}` and where the spacing is hardwired in TeX (based on `\fontdimen` parameters of the math extension font).

Comment: *As above, so below!*

Answer (score 4):

Remedied the valid comment of mh256, creating macro `\xxrightarrow[]{}` that reduces the space of the underset, but allows for the length of the underset.

EDITED to make it `\mathrel` and also to use temp `\box2` instead of `\box0`, which appears to be also used by `\xrightarrow`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\xxrightarrow[2][]{\mathrel{%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\stackon{\scriptstyle#1}{\scriptstyle#2}}%
  \stackunder[0pt]{%
    \xrightarrow{\makebox[\dimexpr\wd2\relax]{$\scriptstyle#2$}}%
  }{%
   \scriptstyle#1\,%
  }%
}}
\parskip 3pt
\begin{document}
\fbox{$\xxrightarrow[\fbox{below}]{\fbox{above}}$}

\fbox{$\xxrightarrow[\fbox{below is a long text}]{\fbox{above}}$}

$ x \xxrightarrow[bottom]{top} y$

$x \xxrightarrow[a]{a} y$

$x \xrightarrow[a]{a} y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is't an extensible arrow. The text below does not influence the length of the arrow in any way.

Comment: @mh256  That is a good point.  I will work to resolve that.

Comment: @mh256 See revision.

Comment: That's better. I don't understand why your solution has a minimum length of the arrow. (`$x \xxrightarrow[a]{a} y$`)

Comment: @mh256  Apparently `\box0` is already being used by `\xrightarrow`, so I merely changed over to `\box2` to take care of the `$x \xxrightarrow[a]{a} y$` use case.  Also, I made the relation a `\mathrel` to obtain proper surrounding spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\myxrightarrow[2][]{
    \xrightarrow[{\raisebox{1.25ex-\heightof{$\scriptstyle#1$}}[0pt]{$\scriptstyle#1$}}]{#2}%
}
\noindent
\fbox{$\xrightarrow[\fbox{below}]{\fbox{above}}$}
\fbox{$\myxrightarrow[\fbox{below}]{\fbox{above}}$}\\
\fbox{$\xrightarrow[below]{above}$}
\fbox{$\myxrightarrow[below]{above}$}\\
\fbox{$\xrightarrow[aaa]{above}$}
\fbox{$\myxrightarrow[aaa]{above}$}\\
\fbox{$\xrightarrow[\int^2]{above}$}
\fbox{$\myxrightarrow[\int^2]{above}$}
\end{document}
```

Advantage: Command with just one line

Disadvantage: Line height is not as small as it could be (see aaa example).

[image]