# How to reduce space proportionally to a symbol's height?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, arrows, xrightarrow, arrowwithtext

I'd like to reduce the vertical space between the arrow and the symbol above it in the `\xrightarrow` command.

Of course, "hard-coding" a value leads to unfortunate results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\myxrightarrow[1]{
    \xrightarrow{\raisebox{-.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle#1}}}
}
\begin{document}

    \(A \myxrightarrow{\theta} B\)
    
    \(A \myxrightarrow{\theta_D'} B\)
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

where the "D" is *on* the arrow line.

**How can I adaptatively reduce this spacing?**

I have read the documentation of the `calc` package and tried various formulas using `heightof`, but none was satisfactory (to say the least…).

*This question is related to, but not solved by, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231918/34551.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `\height` and `\depth` to avoid overlaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\myxrightarrow[1]{
    \xrightarrow{\raisebox{-0.4ex}[\dimexpr \height-0.4ex][\depth]{\ensuremath{\scriptsize#1}}}
}
\begin{document}
    \(A \myxrightarrow{\theta} B\)
    
    \(A \myxrightarrow{\theta_D'} B\)
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Your first idea is really nice and seems to work perfectly for my particular needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can pretend that the arrow is less high than it is. Since TeX uses the height of the symbol it attaches limits to, we'll get a lower upper limit.

Note: `\xrightarrow` basically does

```
\mathrel{\mathop{<extended arrow>}\limits_{<lower label>}^{<upper label>}}}
```

but we just need to adapt the existing macros to our purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
%% straight copy from \xrightarrow in amsmath.sty
%% with \rightarrowfill replaced
\NewDocumentCommand{\myxrightarrow}{m}{%
  \ext@arrow 0359\smashed@rightarrowfill@{}{#1}%
}
%% we want to define \smashed@rightarrowfill
%% like amsmath.sty does for \rightarrowfill
%% but with \smashed@arrow instead of \rightarrow
\newcommand{\smashed@rightarrowfill@}{%
  \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\smashed@rightarrow
}
%% now define \smashed@rightarrow
%% we need \mathpalette
\newcommand{\smashed@rightarrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\smashed@@rightarrow\relax}}
%% we use \raisebox to assign a height
%% the height is that of the formula axis
%% stored in \fontdimen22 <font>2
%% where <font> is one of \textfont, \scriptfont or \scriptscript font
\newcommand{\smashed@@rightarrow}[2]{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\fontdimen22\smashed@font{#1}2]{$\m@th#1\rightarrow$}%
}
%% here we use the current style to select the right font
%% among the three we identified earlier
\newcommand{\smashed@font}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(A \myxrightarrow{\theta} B\) \(A \xrightarrow{\theta} B\)

\(A \myxrightarrow{\theta_D'} B\) \(A \xrightarrow{\theta_D'} B\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very creative, thanks a lot. Is there a "squigarrowfill" to substitute for the "`\arrowfill`"? I couldn't find anything documenting the various types of "\arrowfill" unfortunately.

Comment: @Clément you can do it with TikZ, I believe there’s somoon the site

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how the code works: what does mean the curious constant 0359, why we need to read `\fontdimen22`, etc.

Comment: @wipet Are you happier now? The “curious constant” is actually four independent tokens, as defined in `amsmath.sty`. I'm sure you will understand it as soon as you read the source.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for commenting out your solution so nicely. Many interesting elements in there!

Answer (score 2):

The positioning a box x over relation symbol is implemented using Op math atom with `\limits`, which is described in rule 13a of appendix G in TeXbook. We can read here that the depth of the box x is subtracted when the vertical space between the box and the relation symbol box is calculated, see the expression max(\xi_9,\xi_{11}-d(x)) here. This calculation keeps the baseline of x at constant distance if d(x) isn't too big.

Your solution creates the box x where its depth is zero and its material is shifted down **with respect to its baseline** and extends below the box boundary. The material of box x overlaps the relation symbol because its real depth isn't used in the calculation. Your shifting of box x can be rewritten in primitive TeX language:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\lower.5ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle x$}}\wd0=0 \box0
```

A simple solution of your problem is to create a box with depth zero and the material shifted down **with respect to its bottom**. It can be done by

```
\vbox{\hbox{$\scriptstyle x$}\kern-.5ex}
```

Now the box is shifted but its original depth isn't ignored and its new depth is zero.

You can try:

```
\def\mybuildrel #1\over{\buildrel \vbox{\hbox{$\scriptstyle#1$}\kern-.4ex}\over}

test:
$$
  A \mybuildrel \theta \over \rightarrow B, \quad 
  A \mybuildrel \theta'_D \over \longrightarrow B
$$
\bye
```

Viola, it works.

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem? Try `$\xrightarrow{\theta}$` and `$\buildrel\theta\over\rightarrow$` and you'll get the same output. Which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes indeed I'm not sure I see any change using that command.

Comment: @Clément I rewrote my answer, I explain, what is bad in your macro.